# Self Retaining PCB Connector

Tags: pcb, connector, cables, plug

I hope this is the right place to ask.

I`m looking for a self retaining pcb connector. It should be 2.54mm pitch.
Something like this

[image]

I have a lot of boards that have unpopulated serial ports, I need to do firmware upgrades over thi port and I am looking for a cable or plug that retains inside the holes when I let go the cable.

I don`t know how this is called or even if it exists.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look staggered holes from Sparkfun. https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/114

This keeps the pins 'locked' in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing the layout then the [Tag Connect](http://www.tag-connect.com/) stuff is not bad, use ENIG pads and make sure the locating and mounting holes are to spec and they work well. 
Remember to omit the solder paste from the contact pads!

Some styles of [pogo pin](http://uk.farnell.com/harwin/p25-5223/probe-star-contact-2-54mm-pitch/dp/9960252) will likely work if you make up suitable jigs, very common in production programming.

Comment: Thanks for this, I think I have to figure out a way by myself. The problem is, the PCB are already finished and I hvae this 2.54mm pitch serial port and no chance to change it. The firmware update takes 1 min so it is a game of luck if it works or not :/